# I Can't Adjust My Screen Brightness Using Fn+Arrow Left or Fn+Arrow Right (Acer Aspire V5)

Tags: graphics, screen, brightness

I'm using Acer Aspire V5 (Windows 8). I have a problem regarding my screen brightness. Although I can still adjust it but I can't using <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Left</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Right</kbd>. I visited the ease of access on my settings and tried to turn on *high contrast*. After that, I can't adjust my screen brightness using my keyboard anymore.

Please do help me. Thank you.

Comment: Is this about Ubuntu or Windows 8? Ubuntu has no such "Ease of access" center.